# DomainContext sometimes still HasChanges after SubmitChanges completes

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a very simple server model that includes a parent entity with a [Composition] list of child entities. In my client, I have 2 functions. One function removes all the child entities from the parent and the other removes all and also edits a property on the parent entity.

When I simply remove all child entities and SubmitChanges(), all is well.

When I remove all child entities *and* edit the parent and SubmitChanges(), there are still pending changes (HasChanges == true) when the SubmitChanges() callback is fired.

I am using Silveright 4 RTM and RIA Services 1.0 RTM.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Here are the server entities:

```
public class RegionDto
{
    public RegionDto()
    {
        Cities = new List<CityDto>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("RegionDto_CityDto", "Id", "RegionId")]
    public List<CityDto> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class CityDto
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
public static class CState
{
    private static RegionDomainContext _domainContext;

    public static RegionDomainContext DomainContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_domainContext == null)
            {
                _domainContext = new RegionDomainContext();
            }
            return _domainContext;
        }
    }

    public static void SaveChanges()
    {
        DomainContext.SubmitChanges(op =>
        {
            if (DomainContext.HasChanges && !DomainContext.IsSubmitting)
            {
                var w = new ChildWindow();
                w.Content = "The DomainContext still has unsaved changes.";
                w.Show();
            }
        }, null);
    }
}

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private void ClearCitiesEditRegion(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var region = (RegionDto)regionList.SelectedItem;

        if (region != null)
        {
            region.Name += "*";
            while (region.Cities.Count > 0)
            {
                region.Cities.Remove(region.Cities.First());
            }

            CState.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private void ClearCities(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var region = (RegionDto)regionList.SelectedItem;

        if (region != null)
        {
            while (region.Cities.Count > 0)
            {
                region.Cities.Remove(region.Cities.First());
            }

            CState.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this code the ChildWindow is only shown when you the ClearCitiesEditRegion() method is called. The only difference between this and the ClearCities() method is the line where I edit the region.Name property.

You can also download a sample project that reproduces this here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2393192/RIA_Services_Problem.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received an answer to this on the Silverlight forums. Apparently this is a bug in RIA Service 1.0. The following is [Matthew's response on the Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/183798/418701.aspx#418701).

> Yes, I've confirmed this is a bug.
>   Thanks for reporting it and providing
>   the repro. As you discovered, the bug
>   will only repro in composition
>   scenarios where the parent has been
>   modified in addition to one or more
>   children. The workaround is to do an
>   explicit AcceptChanges if the submit
>   was successful. For example, here is
>   the code you'd write in a submit
>   callback:

```
   if (!submitOperation.HasError)
   {
      ((IChangeTracking)ctxt.EntityContainer).AcceptChanges();
   }
```

> This will accept all changes and reset
>   change state correctly.

Comment: hey what is "ctxt" in his workaround answer? I probably am facing the same issue. Thanks